# Is there a short way of addressing branches in Git?

Tags: git

Is there a shorter way of referring to branches other than typing out their full name?

How would it, for example, look when used with the `git checkout` command?

To better understand the problem I'm having imagine a repository with around 50 branches with names such as:

`/feature/SOMECONSTANT-789738-And-a-very-long-description-copied-from-the-ticket-title`

Such branch names are generated by tools like `Atlassian Stash`. One way of solving this would be local branches with my own short names.

I was wondering if there is another, simpler way of doing it. For example, every local branch could have a number associated with it that one could use to refer to it?

Comment: What do you mean by addressing branches?

Comment: Maybe "referring" to them is a better word? As in "using them with git commands".

Comment: I don't get what you mean. If you are annoyed of branch names, why don't you keep them short?

Comment: Why would you need that? Because you have to type the full branch path?

Comment: Beside the one solution you already provided to use short local branchnames by your self, there is no other way of doing this. And most common terminal emulator supports you with tab-completion(as far as you have included the git-completion.sh from the [git contribution repo](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion) )

Comment: I know that this is not the answer, bu maybe this tip can be also useful for you in other usecases. If you want to switch to the previous branch, you cat use `git checkout -`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just rename your local branch for your own sanity:

```
git branch -m feature/SOMECONSTANT-789738-And-a-very-long-description-copied-from-the-ticket-title f/short-branch
```

This won’t affect the remote branch, and if you have been tracking your remote branch, you can still use `git push` to push to that long name.

Answer (score 3):

you can do the following:
create any branch name you wish and set it to track any remote branch with the long name.

for example:

```
git checkout short_name
git branch -u upstream/long_branch_name
// or
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/long_branch_name
```

Both of the later command will do the same. simply different syntax for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Well, kind of. Git has command line completion that works for a number of shells, so you only have to type the start of your branch name to find and complete it, without throwing away the context that a long branch name allows.

An aside, we've had requests for the ability to better customise the branch name created from JIRA issues, and it's something we're considering.